# How to get related workflow from a Component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Can anyone provide me code snippet for following requirement?

I need to find related workflow object associated with a component. how shall i achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I tried to do this in Template Building Block using c#, could you please provide code snippet for this ?

Comment: Can you add a bit more info on this. What context are you working in (Visio Workflow scripts, Templates, Event System etc)? Please also define what you mean by "related workflow object", and also describe the background of what  you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @user1773981 You have not gone to any effort to make this a useful question. Perhaps you could post some relevant parts of the code you've already written, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it through the Schema the Component is based on, since Workflow is associated to content through Schemas for Components, or through Structure Groups for pages.

After getting the schema you will need to check what workflows are associated with it but it depends on "where" you are trying to achieve this. Could please provide with more details on "WHERE" are you trying to get this information (Template/Event Sýstem/etc...)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I tried to do this in Template Building Block using c#, could you please provide code snippet for this ?

Comment: @user1773981 - This looks like a pretty good answer. To progress further, you can't just ask people to do your job for you. If you have written some code, and experienced problems, then please tell us what you tried and what went wrong.